Why do I get an Invalid Argument Exception when displaying a network image?
Sometimes when I call this code:
Widget displayImage(BuildContext context, MyBook book) {
  if (book.coverUrl != null) {
    try {
      return Image.network(book.coverUrl!,
          errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
        return Text('No \nimage');
      });
    } on Exception {
      return Text('No \nImage');
    }
  } else {
    return Text('No \nImage');
  }
}

I receive the message

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ══════════════════
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in
URI file:///home/alan/FlutterProjects/books/null
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════

(file:///home/alan/FlutterProjects/books/ is my app's path. book.coverUrl is a String.)
The online image displays properly, despite the Exception message.
What causes this? Do I need to fix it?
EDIT:
The end of the stack track also includes the message:

Image provider: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)


Image key: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)


well  file:///home/alan/FlutterProjects/bo.. seems invalid path to me

Image.network is for images from the network, not for images from arbitrary URIs.  If you want to load an image from local storage, use Image.file(File(...)) instead.  You also have a bug somewhere else that is setting coverUrl to the string 'null'.

You need to check image URL:

image URL: ensure that, it's preceded by http:// or https:// as a valid URL
if not, just append that string by https://.


And your condition should be:
if (book.coverUrl != null && book.coverUrl != 'null'){
 // return it here
} 


The url seems invalid, I will prefer short way  like
Widget displayImage(BuildContext context, MyBook book) {
  return Image.network(
    "${book.coverUrl}",// will handle by the errorBuilder
    errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
      return Text('No \nimage');
    },
  );
}



Your code is cleaner and simpler, which I appreciate. Unfortunately, the Exception remains. Thanks for responding, though.

You are passing a path

file:///home/alan/FlutterProjects/books/

into Image.network() which expects a url you need to pass Image.file() for displaying an image that is in your path
sample code is given below
 Widget displayImage(BuildContext context, MyBook book) {
    if (book.coverUrl != null) {
      try {

        return Image.file(File(book.coverUrl!),
            errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
              return Text('No\nImage');
            });
      } on Exception {
        return Text('No\nImage');
      }
    } else {
      return Text('No\nImage');
    }
  }

Mainly there are 4 different types present to show images in flutter right now
Image.asset() 
Image.file() 
Image.network() 
Image.memory()

If you are using MyBook Object dynamically then you have to check if your book.coverUrl is a url or a path to manage it properly with corresponding widgets. Happy Coding :)
